# Fluent nhibernate private field with componentmap

Tags: vb.net, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to map a component(with its own componentmap) to a private field? I've tried, but it then requires a inline mapping of the entity.

It works fine with a public property like this:

```
Component(Function(t) t._ScormSettings)
```

But when trying this:

```
Component(Of ScormSettingsEntity)(Function(t) Reveal.Member(Of ScormPackageEntity)("_ScormSettings"))
```

It wants an func(object) parameter to define mapping.

The ScormSettings-mapping:

```
Public Class ScormSettingsMapping
    Inherits ComponentMap(Of ScormSettingsEntity)

    Sub New()
        Map(Function(t) t.SettingTrackCompleted).Column("SettingTrackCompleted").Nullable()
        Map(Function(t) t.SettingTrackScore).Column("SettingTrackScore").Nullable()
        Map(Function(t) t.SettingTrackCompletedScore).Column("SettingTrackCompletedScore").Nullable()
    End Sub
End Class
```